# Any ways to collect process information?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I currently run:

```
ps -f -u vinish | sort -k5
```

but how can I do this in Python without writing the same quoted command in my code?

For executing bash commands I use `os.system('<cmd>')` or will call through `subprocess`, but I am looking something that won't hold any bash commands in it.

Comment: And what does that command?

Comment: A  lot easier get process info using subprocess,the sorting part is very basic. Why don't you want to use subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort the output from [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess

processes = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-f', '-u', 'vinish'])
for line in sorted(processes.splitlines(), key=lambda l: int(l.split()[1])):
    print(line)
```

This goes one better on the `sort -k5` output in that it extracts the second column and sorts it numerically.

Note that no sub-shell is created (no *bash commands* are being executed here); Python executes the `ps` command directly. This is the easiest way to get process information without installing third-party libraries.

If you really wanted to avoid executing external commands, you'll have to use an add-on library. I recommend the [`psutil` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) here:

```
import psutil

matching = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.username() == 'vinish']
for proc in sorted(matching, key=lambda p: p.pid):
    print(proc)
```

See the [`psutil.Process()` class documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class) for details on what each `proc` object offers in the way of information and functionality.

Comment: The OP does not want to use subprocess, that is the basis of the question to do it without using os.system or subprocess

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That's **your** interpretation. They are looking for something *without bash commands*. Now, it could well be that that means *no external processes*, but that's open for debate.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: there, added a `psutil` option too.

Comment: Second part is the answer to the question, the first does execute bash/shell commands albeit through subprocess.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no, that's at not true; no shell (bash or otherwise) is executed. `/bin/ps` *is* executed, but that's not the same thing; that's not a shell command, it is just another executable.

Comment: I think we can safely consider what the OP considers to be bash commands to include what is in the first part of your answer,  subprocess is not new to them as explicitly explained in their question. Using subprocess alone is almost certainly against the OP's requirements.

Comment: In which case they'll have to install a third-party library. It'd be more helpful if the OP were to clarify **why** they don't want to use that and what their use cases is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for ur answers and comments. And if you find any more alternate ways please do reply me.

Comment: As @PadraicCunningham told, second part is what am looking for.